# Lua multiple concurrent processes

Tags: concurrency, process, lua

I want to execute multiple processes concurrently from a lua script e.g.

```
os.execute("cmd1")
os.execute("cmd2")
os.execute("cmd3")
```

where cmd1,2 and 3 are continually running processes. When i do this as above, cmd2 and 3 will only run when cmd1 is finished. Any idea on this? Should i be using "fork" or something equivalent?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(answer mostly copied from *[Call popen with environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840845/837856)*)

There is an  `os.spawn` function in the [ExtensionProposal](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ExtensionProposal) API.

You can use it as follows:

```
require"ex"
local proc, err = os.spawn{
    command = e.."/bin/aprogr",
    args = {
        "arg1",
        "arg2",
        -- etc
    },
    env = {
        A = 100, -- I assume it tostrings the value
        B = "Hi",
        C = "Test",
    },
    -- you can also specify stdin, stdout, and stderr
    -- see the proposal page for more info
}
if not proc then
    error("Failed to aprogrinate! "..tostring(err))
end

-- if you want to wait for the process to finish:
local exitcode = proc:wait()
```

[lua-ex-pai](http://code.google.com/p/lua-ex-api/) provides implementations for POSIX and Windows.
It allows the spawning of multiple concurrent processes.

You can find precompiled binaries of this implementation bundled with the [LuaForWindows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) distribution.

Here is a more concise version of your use case:

```
require"ex"
local cmd1_out = io.pipe()
local cmd1_proc = assert(os.spawn("cmd", {
    stdout = cmd1_out,
}))
local cmd2_out = io.pipe()
local cmd2_proc = assert(os.spawn("cmd", {
    stdout = cmd1_out,
}))
-- perform actions with cmd1 and cmd2
```

Comment: Does lua-ex-api still maintained? I dont understand google code. Looks odd and old. Any hint on this?

Answer (score 5):

You've got several solutions to your problem:

1. Depending on your operating system shell, you might use `&` to put tasks into the background. For example: `os.execute('(sleep 10&& echo bar) & echo foo')`
2. [Lua Posix](https://github.com/rrthomas/luaposix) comes with a `posix.fork()` function
3. [Lua Lanes](https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes) gives you multithreading in Lua, so you might be able to just use os.execute in separate lanes (note that 'threads' in a Lua context usually refers to coroutines instead of native OS threads).

Comment: It's a old post yea, but does 1. work on windows?

Comment: Yes and no. `os.execute` will work, but the command string has to be changed to something windows-shell specific.

Answer (score 2):

That's because Lua is single threaded. To run it concurrently you'll need to provide a multi-threaded solution for Lua (not coroutines, because they're microthreads!), like [lua pthreads](http://lua51pthread.luaforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Try simply adding & at the end of your commands:

```
os.execute("cmd1 &")
os.execute("cmd2 &")
os.execute("cmd3 &")
```

This should work on an operative system. On windows there might be a way to to the same, but I have no idea of what it is.