# How to run two commands without waiting for the first one to finish

Tags: shell, automation, lua

So here is what i want to do :
I have a lua script here is the code

```
if ( i == "1" ) 
    then
        io.write("Please provide the PHP reverse shell path : ")
        local rev_shell_path = io.read()
        local hex_edit = os.execute("hexeditor " .. rev_shell_path )
        local sendkeys = os.execute("python3 src/sendkeys.py")
    end
```

the job of this code is to run hexedit and then run a python script which uses pyautogui to send some keys which are needed to automate the task of editing the hex codes.
the problem here that for sendkeys.py script to run hexeditor must end or get killed.
How can i run them at the same time without ending hexeditor ?

Comment: Possible duplocate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480315/lua-multiple-concurrent-processes   The thing that I figure best suits your use case is `os.spawn` which is what the accepted answer from that link says.

Comment: `os.execute("hexeditor " .. rev_shell_path .. " &")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua multiple concurrent processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480315/lua-multiple-concurrent-processes)

Comment: It throws this error (module 'ex' not found)